# how to map 1 and 0 for all true and false

Tags: python, pandas

I have two column in dataframe Column_1 and Column_2 if both contain same value then marked it as 1 as 0

I tried this but it return list of size 1 and inside list it contain series of size 416

```
    splitsE = [(df.COLUMN_1.str.contains(' Each')) & 
        (df.COLUMN_2.str.contains(' EACH'))]
```

i even tried this one also but it doesnt map

```
      splitsE = [(df.COLUMN_1.str.contains(' Each')) & 
        (df.COLUMN_2.str.contains(' EACH'))]
    splitsE = list(map(list, zip(*splitsE)))
   df['CASE#'] = pd.Series(splitsE).map(({True:'1', False:'0'}))
```

if i want to update df['CASE#'] where it contain / as 2 in place of 0

```
     COLUMN_3  CASE#  
    25/PACK      0  
    EACH         1 
    100/BOTTLE   0  
    25/PACK      0 
     NaN         0
    3/PACK       0 
    EACH         1
```

Comment: `df['CASE#'] = 1*df.COLUMN_1.str.contains(' Each')*df.COLUMN_2.str.contains(' EACH')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
splitsE = (df.COLUMN_1.str.contains(' Each')) & (df.COLUMN_2.str.contains(' EACH'))
```

I think simpliest is convert boolean mask to integer for `True/False` to `1/0` map:

```
df['CASE#'] = splitsE.astype(int)
```

---

Another solution is use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['CASE#'] = np.where(splitsE, 1, 0)
```

Or `map` with dictionary with removed one `()`:

```
df['CASE#'] = splitsE.map({True:'1', False:'0'})
```

EDIT: For another condition use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
mask1 = df.COLUMN_3.str.contains('EACH', case=False, na=False)
mask2 = df.COLUMN_3.str.contains('/', case=False, na=False)

df['CASE#'] = np.select([mask1, mask2], [1, 2], default=0)
print (df)
     COLUMN_3  CASE#
0     25/PACK      2
1        EACH      1
2  100/BOTTLE      2
3     25/PACK      2
4         NaN      0
5      3/PACK      2
6        EACH      1
```

Comment: hey @jezrael what if i want to update df['CASE#'] wherever it contain (/) it should mark it as two without affecting the previous results

Comment: yes just lookingg into column_3 if it contain / uptaed it with 2

Comment: @PURU - Edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question, here is the solution:

```
import pandas as pd
data =  [[1,2], [2,5], [3,3], [4,7],[9,9], [6,5]]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2'], data=data)
df.head()
```

[image: df.head() table]

```
df['comp'] = 1 * (df['col1'] == df['col2'])
df.head()
```

[image: df.head() table 2]

Comment: `df['comp'] = 1 * (df['col1'] == df['col2'])` is a much faster and more direct approach to the solution you are showing.